# Combo box that shows only certain sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

create combo box that only shows certain sheet instead of all available sheets,plus the ability to click on the sheet even when hidden?

am using forms controls comboBox, In Payment Code

```
Private Sub cbSheet_Change()

If cbSheet.Value <> "Select a Sheet" Then
Worksheets(cbSheet.Value).Select
End If
    cbSheet.Value = "Select a Sheet"
End Sub  


Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

Dim Sh As Worksheet
Me.cbSheet.Clear
For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
Me.cbSheet.AddItem Sh.Name
Next Sh
End Sub
```

In ThisWorkBook code

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

If ActiveSheet.Name = "Master Data" Then
Worksheets("Report").Select
Worksheets("Master Data").Select
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When looping through the sheets, you can make sure not to add the sheet you don't want in the combobox

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, s As String
    s = Me.ComboBox1
    If s = "" Then Exit Sub
    Set sh = Sheets(s)
    With sh
        If .Visible = False Then
            .Visible = True
        End If
        .Select
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Me.ComboBox1.Clear
    For Each sh In Sheets
        If sh.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
            Me.ComboBox1.AddItem sh.Name
        End If
    Next sh
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

The code should add the hidden sheet names

### Adding specific sheets the the combbox

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Me.ComboBox1.Clear

    With Me.ComboBox1
        .AddItem "Sheet2"
        .AddItem "Sheet4"
        .AddItem "Sheet5"
        .AddItem "Sheet6"
    End With

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: May I know, what is the coding if I only want certain sheet in the combo box?